# Remove text in between delimiters in a string - regex? when the string has '/'

Tags: c#, regex, string

This is the string I have. Script:

```
Select * from tablename()

/*

go

*/
```

My code looks like this

```
private string RemoveBetween(string editScript, char begin, char end)
{
   Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("///.*?///", begin, end));
   return  regex.Replace(editScript, string.Empty);
}

editscript = RemoveBetween(editscript, '/', '/');
```

AM unable to remove the text between `/*----*/`.

Comment: What's the point of `string.Format("whatever string", begin, end)` if you don't have placeholders for the parameters?

Comment: @Amit Joki You should not have put "C# - " at the beginning of the title. This is what tags are for!

Comment: @Kazark, I didn't put it.

Comment: @AmitJoki Odd. The edit history says you did. No worries, I took it back out.

Comment: @Kazark, how to see edit history. can you please tell me?

Comment: @AmitJoki http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22406132/revisions

Answer (score 1):

```
private string RemoveBetween(String editScript, String begin, String end)
{
   return Regex.Replace(editScript,
                        String.Format("{0}.*?{1}", begin, end),
                        String.Empty,
                        RegexOptions.Singleline)
}
```

usage:

```
editscript = RemoveBetween(editscript, "/", "/");
```

I've changed your signature to use `String`, because you probably might want to call it like so (to remove SQL comment blocks):

```
editscript = RemoveBetween(editscript, "/\*", "\*/");
```

Comment: +1 Yes you spotted the real problem. I'd like to suggest that you use [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) to safely escape the input strings.

Comment: What if I have a sql script select N'/* test*/' as data.i tried using the Regex "/\\*.*(?<=\\*/)". it fails

Comment: @lkjhgfdsa You are hopefully aware that if you're to follow this line of thought, you'd end up with a generic-regex-SQL-parser, which would be a bloated, unreliable monster? A reasonable solution here would be to store all strings between ' (and ") separately, remove them temporarily and re-add after removing comments.